# Google Map API call for route/direction with only coordinate points in lattitude, longitude

Tags: google-maps-api-3

If I have 2 GPS points hwo I can call the Google Map API?

normally you would call like  http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=XXX301&daddr=YYY.
Instead of address string how would it handle if knowing two GPS points?

Comment: This is not actually the Google Maps API but directly using Google Maps, a different story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://maps.google.com/?saddr=startLat,startLng&daddr=endLat,endLng